# How to initiate connection to aws sqs in golang

Tags: go, microservices, amazon-sqs

I am building microservices application in golang, and each service talks to another service through sqs, however, i am having the difficulty to initiate the sqs connection when the server is up, so how do i initiate the sqs connection and use it in my service. building the service using go-kit so i have a file named service.go, main.go, endpoint.go and transport.go.

basically i have the code for the connection

```
creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, token)
    cfg := aws.NewConfig().WithRegion("region").WithCredentials(creds)
    service := sqs.New(session.New(), cfg)
    qURL := "q_url"

    receive_params := &sqs.ReceiveMessageInput{
        QueueUrl:            aws.String(qURL),
        MaxNumberOfMessages: aws.Int64(1),
        VisibilityTimeout:   aws.Int64(30),
        WaitTimeSeconds:     aws.Int64(1),
    }
    receive_resp, err := service.ReceiveMessage(receive_params)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("[Receive message] \n%v \n\n", receive_resp)
    return true, nil
```

so how do i initiate the connection and start getting the messages in my services. Thank you all.

Comment: ...and what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should retrieve messages but it is instructed to fetch the messages once.

You'd need to put into some loop like such and probably run it on another goroutine if the app needs to run something else concurrently.

```
go func() {
  for {
    receive_resp, err := service.ReceiveMessage(receive_params)
    if err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("[Receive message] \n%v \n\n", receive_resp)
  }
}()
```

[Reference on ReceiveMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/sqs/#SQS.ReceiveMessage)

[Reference on Short vs Long polling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html)